# Changing Line colour dynamically core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to change the line colour of the core plot graph dynamically
.The requirement is to have different colours for different portions of the same line graph plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll need multiple line plots, one for each color.

Comment: In this case how to adjust the number in plot method to colour the sample points with different point arriving at real time.

Comment: Use the [`-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_scatter_plot_data_source-p.html#a06a9046c6f6e72989154d2b65cd983fc) datasource method to provide plot symbols for each data point. Each one can be unique.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the help.